# ngx-bootstrap: close and reopen modal from its child modal

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

In my Angular 4 application, I have a ngx-boostrap Modal made as a [Modal Component](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-component).

In my modal there is a form. When the form is dirty, I would like to prevent the user from just closing the modal. Instead I would like to:

- close (temporarely) the modal (maintaining its contents)
- open another (child) modal with a confirmation message "are you sure?" "yes"/"no"
- if the user clicks "no", the child modal should just disappear and the parent modal should be re-shown with the same status as before

how can I accomplish that?

Comment: If you're able to use their nested formula on that link, you can just add a [hidden] attribute to the parent template. Set it to true when you click to open the 2nd modal, set to false when they close the 2nd.

Comment: @Z.Bagley  the nested formula on that link is referring to [Modal Template](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-template). As I said, I'm using a [Modal Component](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-component) instead.

Comment: another option is to have some routing in the modal, and create a routing guard